# Pyspark how to convert columns to maps after grouping and pivoting

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, pyspark, multiple-columns

How to convert multiple columns to maps after grouping and pivoting in pyspark. Code below is not working as expected.

**Input dataframe:**

| ID | TYPE | Order | Address | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Primary | abc | 111 |
| 1 | B | Primary | def | 222 |
| 1 | A | Secondary | ghi | 333 |
| 1 | B | Secondary | jkl | 444 |
| 2 | A | Primary | mno | 555 |
| 2 | A | Secondary | pqr | 666 |
| 2 | B | Primary | stu | 777 |
| 2 | B | Secondary | vwy | 888 |

**Expected Output dataframe:**

| ID | Primary_A_attributes | Primary_B_attributes | Secondary_A_attributes | Secondary_B_attributes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {"Address" : "abc", "phone" : "111"} | {"Address" : "def", phone" : "222"} | {"Address" : "ghi", "phone" : "333"} | {"Address" : "jkl", phone" : "444"} |
| 2 | {"Address":"mno", "phone":"555" | {"Address" : "pqr", phone" : "666"} | {"Address":"stu", "phone":"777" | {"Address" : "vwy", phone" : "888"} |

**code used:**

```
df.withColumn("collection",F.upper(F.concat_ws('_attributes_','order','type')))\
.groupBy('id').pivot("collection").agg(F.create_map(F.lit("Address"),F.col("Address")\
F.lit("phone"),F.col("phone"))).display()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

desired solution :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W
data =[("1","A","Primary","abc","111"),
("1","B","Primary","def","222"),
("1","A","Secondary","ghi","333"),
("1","B","Secondary","jkl","444"),
("2","A","Primary","mno","555"),
("2","A","Secondary","pqr","666"),
("2","B","Primary","stu","777"),
("2","B","Secondary","vwy","888")]
schema=["ID","TYPE","Order","Address","Phone"]
df_source = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema)
expr_array=F.array(F.lit("Address"),F.lit("Phone"))
df_fnl = df_source.withColumn("collection",F.concat_ws('_','order','type'))\
.groupBy(["id"]).pivot("collection").agg(F.map_from_arrays(expr_array,F.array_union(F.collect_list("Address"),F.collect_list("Phone"))))

df_fnl.select([F.col(col).alias(col+"_attributes") if col !='id' else col for col in df_fnl.columns ]).show(10,0)

OUTPUT :
---+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|id |Primary_A_attributes           |Primary_B_attributes           |Secondary_A_attributes         |Secondary_B_attributes         |
+---+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|1  |{Address -> abc, Phone -> 111}|{Address -> def, Phone -> 222}|{Address -> ghi, Phone -> 333}|{Address -> jkl, Phone -> 444}|
|2  |{Address -> mno, Phone -> 555}|{Address -> stu, Phone -> 777}|{Address -> pqr, Phone -> 666}|{Address -> vwy, Phone -> 888}|
+---+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

kindly UPVOTE IF YOU LIKE MY SOLUTION .

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please help in updating this scenario for multiple values for a single key. like this. {address -> abc,def phone -> 111,222}

Comment: @pradeepnadarajan  kindly share the data and expected out put so that i can try by myself.

if you like my answer , kindly upvote .

Answer (score 1):

You can first create the maps and then use `first()` to fill the values in pivot.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('collection', func.lower(func.concat_ws('_attributes_', 'order', 'type'))). \
    withColumn('adr_ph_struct', 
               func.array(*[func.struct(func.lit(k).alias('key'), func.col(k).alias('val')) for k in ['address', 'phone']])
               ). \
    withColumn('adr_ph_map', func.map_from_entries('adr_ph_struct')). \
    groupBy('id'). \
    pivot('collection'). \
    agg(func.first('adr_ph_map')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
# |id |primary_attributes_a          |primary_attributes_b          |secondary_attributes_a        |secondary_attributes_b        |
# +---+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
# |1  |{address -> abc, phone -> 111}|{address -> def, phone -> 222}|{address -> ghi, phone -> 333}|{address -> jkl, phone -> 444}|
# |2  |{address -> mno, phone -> 555}|{address -> stu, phone -> 777}|{address -> pqr, phone -> 666}|{address -> vwy, phone -> 888}|
# +---+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

---

The data before the `groupBy().pivot()` would look like this

```
# +---+----+---------+-------+-----+----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
# |id |type|order    |address|phone|collection            |adr_ph_struct                 |adr_ph_map                    |
# +---+----+---------+-------+-----+----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
# |1  |A   |Primary  |abc    |111  |primary_attributes_a  |[{address, abc}, {phone, 111}]|{address -> abc, phone -> 111}|
# |1  |B   |Primary  |def    |222  |primary_attributes_b  |[{address, def}, {phone, 222}]|{address -> def, phone -> 222}|
# |1  |A   |Secondary|ghi    |333  |secondary_attributes_a|[{address, ghi}, {phone, 333}]|{address -> ghi, phone -> 333}|
# |1  |B   |Secondary|jkl    |444  |secondary_attributes_b|[{address, jkl}, {phone, 444}]|{address -> jkl, phone -> 444}|
# |2  |A   |Primary  |mno    |555  |primary_attributes_a  |[{address, mno}, {phone, 555}]|{address -> mno, phone -> 555}|
# |2  |A   |Secondary|pqr    |666  |secondary_attributes_a|[{address, pqr}, {phone, 666}]|{address -> pqr, phone -> 666}|
# |2  |B   |Primary  |stu    |777  |primary_attributes_b  |[{address, stu}, {phone, 777}]|{address -> stu, phone -> 777}|
# |2  |B   |Secondary|vwy    |888  |secondary_attributes_b|[{address, vwy}, {phone, 888}]|{address -> vwy, phone -> 888}|
# +---+----+---------+-------+-----+----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please help in updating this scenario for multiple values for a single key. like this. {address -> abc,def phone -> 111,222}

Comment: @pradeepnadarajan you can first group by key columns and use concat_ws(',', collect_list()). it'll be similar to one of your previous question where I amswered.